# Excel Combobox ListFillRange RC adressing

Tags: excel, combobox

I need to populate an Excel combobox via Properties - Combobox window, ListFillRange property (NOT through code). I am able to do it if I put in A1:A10, but I need it in RC style. (1,1);(1,10) style. Is it possible? How?

Comment: **Why** do you need it like that?

Comment: Making a 'cookbook' about how to create this one for non programmer users. For some reason they really like this kind of combobox and not the other (non programmer friendly) one.
Some of them use RC way of adressing. Managed to partially bypass it - named areas. Give it custom name and then it can be called from ListFillRange.

Comment: All they need to do is enter it as say `Sheet1R1C1:R10C1` and Excel will automatically change it to the relevant A1 style address.

Comment: Yup, that works. Would mark it as an answer, but can not do that for a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All they need to do is enter it as say `Sheet1!R1C1:R10C1` and Excel will automatically change it to the relevant A1 style address